# Re-ask a question to settle a micro argument affecting the best answer?

Tags: discussion

On a recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923999/451969), I felt like the best answer wasn't *necessarily* complete*. However, I don't have a good enough understanding to know if my (somewhat nitpicky?) "problem" is right or not.

So I don't want to post it as an answer. Naturally.

My question is, I can't *really* ask a "follow-up" question without *restating* the initial question, ie, duplicating it. How should I resolve this "quandary"?

<sub>* Yes, it is bugging me I don't *know* whose right. I quote Don Rumsfeld, for gosh darn. Whateva.</sub>

Comment: Note that the green check-mark does *not* mean "best". It only means the asker of the question picked it. Sometime the asker is not well positioned as a judge of "best".

Comment: Why do you think a new question will have a better chance of settling the argument than the existing 20+ comments have?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - But I'm trying to understand if hoisting declares before execution, and if execution is right-side, left, ie, `x = x...`, `x` left-side is not "declared" until the execution right-side is complete. Personally, that's what the OP in that question "meant".

Comment: If it's a different question, then ask a new question. I'm not sure where the dilemma is...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - It's not a different question (IMO), it's a more *complete* question, and yes it's "mumble mumble wobble wobbly", BUT... I have to know the details. And uh, nice avatar. It really has more to do with me wanting to know what I have in that comment to you above.

Comment: This is why SO needs to add an endpoint "canonical" Q&A format in addition to the present "feeder" type Q&A format - along with a Wiki type "talk" (aka "comments") format behind the scenes to hash out the details of a question & answer. It would be such a great leap forward.

Comment: @dmckee - I deleted my original response, since I think that's a good comment to keep here; it's certainly valid for other users with less experience. Thanks.

Comment: @skinnyTOD - That's certainly an interesting response. That sounds like something... Specific. Are you talking about something already out there, e.g., wikipedia or whatnot?

Comment: It would be something new/additional - perhaps what community wikis were meant to be except...they really aren't. I mean basically a way for interested parties to really work together to refine both the question and a near as possible 'canonical' answer, which could then be copy edited and presented without all the discussion being displayed (but available if someone is interested in more detail or contrasting POVs - as in the Wikipedia "talk" pages).  Of course, this is not appropriate for all questions or all users but for so many questions (and all their duplicate brethren...) it would be.

Comment: @skinnyTOD - Well, I would encourage you to add that as an answer (beware the meaningless downvotes on meta, though, that's just how people would feel about it, not you; I don't know how the community might respond).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with that domain to know for sure, but it sounds like you still have a related question that isn't solved in those answers. If the answerer is focusing on a part of the OP's question you consider less relevant, then I think at this point you're best to start a new detailed question, making sure to emphasize the part of the question that you feel was missed in the previous answers, and maybe mention the existing question for background (similar to how you have linked to that answer in your question here).

Oh yeah, and nice avatar.

Comment: Nice avatar. Since this works to my desire to reask the question, `+1`! In all seriousness, I do agree. Let me see if I get any other answers.

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. I am *appalled* I have to accept this as *the answer*. Appalled. `;)`

Comment: ..unsure whether I should flag this for sock-puppetry...avatars are too suspicious..

Comment: @Bart ha ha, indeed

Comment: @Bart - HE is the meme. `:P`